# how do i track engagement and conversion in google analytics of a specific button call to action?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have a product page with the following call to actions:
1) Add Monogramming
2) Add Personalization
3) Add Product to Bag

'Add Monogram' button will make the text entry field visible to user to enter their monogram characters.

'Add Personalization' will confirm the monogram addition to the product the user is viewing.

'Add to Bag' will convert to bag.

I would like to report against the following:

Product #, # of prod page views, # monogram views (when 'add monogram' was clicked', # of monogram added ('add personalization' clicked), # of products w/ monogram added to bag ('add to bag' clicked), #units, $total of product added, $total product completed checkout

Any suggestions on what the best way to track this?

Answer (score 1):

For simple tracking of buttons clicks you can use Universal Analytics Events:

```
<button id="add_to_bag">Add to bag</button>

<script>
var addToCartButton = document.getElementById('add_to_bag');
addListener(addToCartButton, 'click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Buttons', 'Add to cart click', 'Product name');
});
</script>
```

But if you want to track a full sales cycle(how many products was shown, detaily viewed, added to cart, removed from cart, sold, etc.) I recommend you to use [Universal Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce).